# Guidelines for product name protection

Tags: trademark

What are the necessary steps to protect a product name for a subscription based cloud application?

Primarly I want to target the EU-market, though theoretically the product could be used worldwide.
Outside of the EU, I specifically plan to target Russia, and the Russian speaking countries as well.

What I did so far:

- I own the domain name which corresponds to the product name
- I have started a trademark protection application (EUTM) with the European Union Intellectual property office. This includes the product name, product service category and a product logo.

In case the EUTM registration completes and confirms my trademark ownership, can I feel safe and market the product?